# Generalised Lambert W and irreducible polynomials

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I want to find the root of a function $f$ defined as

$$ f(x)= e^{-cx} - \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}$$

where $x,c$ are real numbers and $P_n,Q_m$ are irreducible polynomials of rank $n$ and $m$ respectively, whose coefficients depend on $c$. If I understand the current state of the art, a closed-form solution for $x$ can be expressed in terms of the generalised Lambert W only if $P$ and $Q$ are reducible, i.e. can be factorised to $P_n=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-t_i)$ and $Q_m=\prod_{i=0}^m(x-t_i)$. Is this really the case or am I misunderstanding the literature (I am not a mathematician)? In the literature I do not see an explicit discussion of this issue with irreducible polynomials.

So far I based myself on:

[István Mező, Árpád Baricz: On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[Aude Maignan, Tony Scott: Fleshing out the Generalized Lambert W Function. ACM Commun Comp Alg 50 (2016) (2) 45-60](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01326771)

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-cx}-\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}=0$$
$$-\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}=-e^{-cx}$$
$$\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}=e^{-cx}$$
$$\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}e^{cx}=1$$

Each polynomial with complex coefficients can be factorized over the complex numbers. This is stated by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).
Now you can apply Generalized Lambert W.