# Resolution of an system

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

My question is how we can find the analytical solution of the following system
$$ c \ln\left(\dfrac{u}{y}\right)= J x,$$
$$c(u-y)= \left(\dfrac{A}{B x+ D} x + G\right) x,$$
where $u,c, D, A$ et $J$ are constants, and $x$ et $y$ are uknowns.
I try to use Wolfram Alpha but it answer me to give a real values of parameters

We are note interested by the trivial solution $u=y$ and $x=0$

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=\frac u z$. So, the first equation gives $z=e^{\frac{J x}{c}}$.

Plug in the second equation and isolate the exponential term
$$e^{-\frac{J x}{c}}=\frac {-(A+B G)x^2+ (B c u-D G)x+c d
   u } {cu(Bx+D) }$$

the solution of which being given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the paper).

Comment: Than you for the answer. The equation in you're answer have not the same form of the equation (4) in the paper. Can you give the formula of the solution $x$? Please

Comment: @mati. Have a look at   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567434/generalised-lambert-w-and-irreducible-polynomials

Comment: Please Professor, please can you write me the formula of the solution of my equation using thegeneralized Lambert function and the formula of Lambert function? I'm lost